# PRAW: How do you get your submission link?

Tags: python, reddit, submission, praw

```
def self_post():
for i in sub_reddit:

    reddit.subreddit(i).submit(post_title, url=post_body)
    print("posted on " + i)
    print(submission.permalink)
    submission.reply('This is a test reply')
    print(submission.permalink)
```

posting the thread works just fine, but i'm trying to get the post URL, then reply to that submission, how would i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `submit` method returns the submission that has been created. So you can save it by doing

```py
submission = reddit.subreddit(subreddit).submit(post_title, selftext=post_body)
```

You can also get the comment created via `reply` by saving the result of calling that method:

```py
comment = submission.reply('This is a test reply')
```

Then your function becomes:

```py
def self_post(post_title, post_body):
    for subreddit in sub_reddit:
        submission = reddit.subreddit(subreddit).submit(post_title, url=post_body)
        print("posted on " + subreddit)
        print(submission.permalink)
        reply = submission.reply('This is a test reply')
        print(reply.permalink)
```